# How to solve "Element type is invalid" for my React app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to better structure my initial code.

https://codesandbox.io/s/jqvkqy29w

However I have problems with integrating children components. As an example here I show how I import a child component `TopControls`. Also I am not sure if I imported `styles` correctly.

Below I show the code of a main root component. The problem is that the page is empty and `TopControls` is not loaded. When I open console, I see the following warnings and errors (I use `"react": "^16.6.0"` and `"react-dom": "^16.6.0"`).

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
>   (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your
>   component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up
>   default and named imports.
>
> Check your code at Main.js:113.
>       in _default (at App.js:21)
>       in App (at src/index.js:5)
>
> react-dom.development.js:57 Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid:
>   expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for
>   composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export
>   your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed
>   up default and named imports.
>
> Check the render method of `_default`.
>       at invariant (react-dom.development.js:57)
>       at createFiberFromTypeAndProps (react-dom.development.js:10531)
>       at createFiberFromElement (react-dom.development.js:10551)
>       at createChild (react-dom.development.js:13811)
>       at reconcileChildrenArray (react-dom.development.js:14080)
>       at reconcileChildFibers (react-dom.development.js:14430)
>       at reconcileChildren (react-dom.development.js:14817)
>       at finishClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:15161)
>       at updateClassComponent (react-dom.development.js:15096)
>       at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:15980)
>       at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:19102)
>       at workLoop (react-dom.development.js:19143)
>       at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:147)
>       at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:196)
>       at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:250)
>       at replayUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:18350)
>       at renderRoot (react-dom.development.js:19261)
>       at performWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:20165)
>       at performWork (react-dom.development.js:20075)
>       at performSyncWork (react-dom.development.js:20049)
>       at interactiveUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:20337)
>       at interactiveUpdates (react-dom.development.js:2267)
>       at dispatchInteractiveEvent (react-dom.development.js:5083) invariant @ react-dom.development.js:57 createFiberFromTypeAndProps @
>   react-dom.development.js:10531 createFiberFromElement @
>   react-dom.development.js:10551 createChild @
>   react-dom.development.js:13811 reconcileChildrenArray @
>   react-dom.development.js:14080 reconcileChildFibers @
>   react-dom.development.js:14430 reconcileChildren @
>   react-dom.development.js:14817 finishClassComponent @
>   react-dom.development.js:15161 updateClassComponent @
>   react-dom.development.js:15096 beginWork @
>   react-dom.development.js:15980 performUnitOfWork @
>   react-dom.development.js:19102 workLoop @
>   react-dom.development.js:19143 callCallback @
>   react-dom.development.js:147 invokeGuardedCallbackDev @
>   react-dom.development.js:196 invokeGuardedCallback @
>   react-dom.development.js:250 replayUnitOfWork @
>   react-dom.development.js:18350 renderRoot @
>   react-dom.development.js:19261 performWorkOnRoot @
>   react-dom.development.js:20165 performWork @
>   react-dom.development.js:20075 performSyncWork @
>   react-dom.development.js:20049 interactiveUpdates$1 @
>   react-dom.development.js:20337 interactiveUpdates @
>   react-dom.development.js:2267 dispatchInteractiveEvent @
>   react-dom.development.js:5083 index.js:1446 The above error occurred
>   in the <_default> component:
>       in _default (at App.js:21)
>       in App (at src/index.js:5)

**Root component "Main.js":**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import TopControls from "./layout/single/TopControls"
import styles from "./layout/single/styles"


export default class extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          holdingTime: 1,
          plannedDep: "2017-05-24T10:30",
          schedTurnd: 45,
          asma40: 100,
          asma60: 500,
          taxiInTime: 9.50,
          wake: 84.73,
          temperature: 20,
          visibility: 5999.66,
          windIntensity: 8.0,
          arrivalDelay: 5,
          distanceTarget: 500,
          airport: "LEBL",
          delay: 0,
          delay_probability: 0,
          delay_cat: "NA",
          chartDataWake: [],
          chartDataTurnaround: [],
          chartDataArrivalDelay: [],
          chartDataDistanceTarget: [],
          labelWidth: 0
      };
      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  };

  componentDidMount() {
      this.fetchData();
  };

  updateDelay(predicted_delay,delay_probability) {
      this.state.chartDataWake = [...this.state.chartDataWake, {wake: this.state.wake===84.73 ? "H" : (this.state.wake===14.78 ? "M" : "L"), delay: predicted_delay}];
      this.state.chartDataTurnaround = [...this.state.chartDataTurnaround, {turnaround: this.state.schedTurnd, delay: predicted_delay}];
      this.state.chartDataArrivalDelay = [...this.state.chartDataArrivalDelay, {arrivalDelay: this.state.arrivalDelay, delay: predicted_delay}];
      this.state.chartDataDistanceTarget = [...this.state.chartDataDistanceTarget, {distanceTarget: this.state.distanceTarget, delay: predicted_delay}];
      this.setState({
        delay: predicted_delay,
        delay_probability: delay_probability,
        delay_cat: predicted_delay===0 ? "<15" : (predicted_delay===1 ? "[15; 45]" : ">45")
      });
  };

  fetchData = () => {
      const url = "http://localhost:8000?"+
        'holdingTime='+this.state.holdingTime+
        '&plannedDep='+this.state.plannedDep+
        '&schedTurnd='+this.state.schedTurnd+
        '&asma40='+this.state.asma40+
        '&asma60='+this.state.asma60+
        '&taxiInTime='+this.state.taxiInTime+
        '&wake='+this.state.wake+
        '&temperature='+this.state.temperature+
        '&visibility='+this.state.visibility+
        '&windIntensity='+this.state.windIntensity+
        '&arrivalDelay='+this.state.arrivalDelay+
        '&distanceTarget='+this.state.distanceTarget;

      fetch(url, {
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        }
      })
      .then((resp) => {
        return resp.json()
      })
      .then((data) => {
        this.updateDelay(data.prediction,data.probability)
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error, "catch the hoop")
      })
  };

  handleChange = (name, event) => {
    this.setState({
      [name]: event.target.value
    }, () => {
      console.log("plannedDep",this.state.plannedDep)
    });
  };


  handleReset = () => {
      this.setState({
          chartDataWake: [],
          chartDataTurnaround: [],
          chartDataArrivalDelay: [],
          chartDataDistanceTarget: [],
          delay: 0,
          delay_probability: 0,
          delay_cat: "NA"
      });
  };

  render() {
    return <Fragment>

      <TopControls state={this.state} handleChange={this.handleChange} styles={styles} />

    </Fragment>
  }
}
```

**styles.js**

```
const styles = theme => ({
    header: {
        borderBottom: 'solid 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)',
        backgroundColor: '#253069',
        color: '#d2d6ef',
        overflow: 'hidden',
        boxShadow: '0 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.2)',
        position: 'relative',
        height: '12%'
    },
    h1: {
        fontSize: '30px',
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
        lineHeight: '1.45em',
        webkitFontSmoothing: 'antialiased'
    },
    h3: {
        fontSize: '20px',
        textAlign: 'left',
        fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
        lineHeight: '1.45em',
        marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit*2,
        webkitFontSmoothing: 'antialiased'
    },
    appBar: {
      top: 'auto',
      bottom: 5,
      height: '10%'
    },
    toolbar: {
      alignItems: "center",
      justifyContent: "space-between"
    },
    textField: {
      fontSize: '12px',
      margin: theme.spacing.unit,
      minWidth: 120
    },
    formControl: {
      fontSize: '12px',
      margin: theme.spacing.unit,
      minWidth: 120
    },
    predictedDelay: {
        marginTop: '10px',
        position: 'relative',
        minWidth: 350,
        maxWidth: 350,
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(225, 0, 80)'
    },
    predictedDelayText: {
        fontSize: '18px'
    },
    topControls: {
        borderBottom: '1px solid #ddd',
        height: '25%',
        boxShadow: '0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.08)',
        background: 'white',
        marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit*2,
        marginRight: theme.spacing.unit*2,
    },
    mainPart: {
        webkitJustifyContent: 'space-between',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
        marginTop: '30px',
        marginBottom: '50px',
        paddingTop: '2px',
        position: 'relative',
        backgroundColor: '#f7f7f7'
    },
    card: {
        maxWidth: 200
    },
    paper: {
        backgroundColor: '#f7f7f7',
        padding: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
        height: '70%',
        marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
        marginRight: theme.spacing.unit * 2,
    },
    buttons: {
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    },
    rightIcon: {
        marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit,
    },
    button: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing.unit * 3,
        marginLeft: theme.spacing.unit,
    }
});
```

**TopControls**

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import Input from '@material-ui/core/Input';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import InputAdornment from '@material-ui/core/InputAdornment';

export default class extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <Fragment>
            <CssBaseline />

            <div className={this.props.styles.header}>
              <h1 className={this.props.styles.h1}>
                Prediction of departure delays for a single flight
              </h1>
            </div>

            <div className={this.props.styles.topControls}>
              <Grid container spacing={24}>
                <Grid item xs={2}>
                  <TextField
                      required
                      id="outlined-simple-start-adornment"
                      className={this.props.styles.textField}
                      onChange={(event) => this.props.handleChange("holdingTime", event)}
                      value={this.props.state.holdingTime}
                      margin="normal"
                      label="Holding time"
                      type="number"
                      InputProps={{
                          startAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start">(seconds)</InputAdornment>,
                      }}
                      onInput = {(e) =>{
                          e.target.value = Math.max(0, parseInt(e.target.value) ).toString().slice(0,12)
                      }}
                  />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={2}>
                  <TextField
                      required
                      id="standard-number"
                      label="Additional ASMA 40"
                      onChange={(event) => this.props.handleChange("asma40", event)}
                      value={this.props.state.asma40}
                      type="number"
                      className={this.props.styles.textField}
                      margin="normal"
                      InputProps={{
                          startAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start">(seconds)</InputAdornment>,
                      }}
                  />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={2}>
                  <TextField
                      required
                      id="standard-number"
                      label="Additional ASMA 60"
                      onChange={(event) => this.props.handleChange("asma60", event)}
                      value={this.props.state.asma60}
                      type="number"
                      className={this.props.styles.textField}
                      margin="normal"
                      InputProps={{
                          startAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start">(seconds)</InputAdornment>,
                      }}
                  />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={2}>
                  <TextField
                    required
                    name="plannedDep"
                    id="datetime-local"
                    onChange={(event) => this.props.handleChange("plannedDep", event)}
                    value={this.props.state.plannedDep}
                    label="Scheduled departure"
                    type="datetime-local"
                    className={this.props.styles.textField}
                    margin="normal"
                    InputLabelProps={{
                      shrink: true,
                    }}
                  />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={2}>
                  <TextField
                      required
                      id="standard-number"
                      label="Planned turnaround"
                      onChange={(event) => this.props.handleChange("schedTurnd", event)}
                      value={this.props.state.schedTurnd}
                      type="number"
                      className={this.props.styles.textField}
                      margin="normal"
                      InputProps={{
                          startAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start">(minutes)</InputAdornment>,
                      }}
                      onInput = {(e) =>{
                          e.target.value = Math.max(0, parseInt(e.target.value) ).toString().slice(0,12)
                      }}
                  />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={2}>
                  <TextField
                      required
                      id="standard-number"
                      label="Taxi-In time"
                      onChange={(event) => this.props.handleChange("taxiInTime", event)}
                      value={this.props.state.taxiInTime}
                      type="number"
                      className={this.props.styles.textField}
                      margin="normal"
                      InputProps={{
                          startAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start">(seconds)</InputAdornment>,
                      }}
                      onInput = {(e) =>{
                          e.target.value = Math.max(0, parseInt(e.target.value) ).toString().slice(0,12)
                      }}
                  />
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
              <Grid container spacing={24}>
                <Grid item xs={2}>
                    <FormControl
                        required
                        className={this.props.styles.formControl}
                        margin="normal">
                        <InputLabel shrink htmlFor="wake-label-placeholder">
                                Wake
                        </InputLabel>
                        <Select
                          onChange={(event) => this.props.handleChange("wake", event)}
                          value={this.props.state.wake}
                          input={<Input name="wake" id="wake-label-placeholder" />}
                          displayEmpty
                          name="wake"
                        >
                          <MenuItem value={84.73}>Heavy</MenuItem>
                          <MenuItem value={14.78}>Medium</MenuItem>
                          <MenuItem value={0.49}>Light</MenuItem>
                        </Select>
                    </FormControl>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={2}>
                  <TextField
                      required
                      id="standard-number"
                      label="Temperature"
                      onChange={(event) => this.props.handleChange("temperature", event)}
                      value={this.props.state.temperature}
                      type="number"
                      className={this.props.styles.textField}
                      margin="normal"
                      InputProps={{
                          startAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start">(Celsius)</InputAdornment>,
                      }}
                  />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={2}>
                  <TextField
                      required
                      id="standard-number"
                      label="Visibility"
                      onChange={(event) => this.props.handleChange("visibility", event)}
                      value={this.props.state.visibility}
                      type="number"
                      className={this.props.styles.textField}
                      margin="normal"
                      InputProps={{
                          startAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start"></InputAdornment>,
                      }}
                      onInput = {(e) =>{
                          e.target.value = Math.max(0, parseInt(e.target.value) ).toString().slice(0,12)
                      }}
                  />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={2}>
                  <TextField
                      required
                      id="standard-number"
                      label="Wind Intensity"
                      onChange={(event) => this.props.handleChange("windIntensity", event)}
                      value={this.state.windIntensity}
                      type="number"
                      className={this.props.styles.textField}
                      margin="normal"
                      InputProps={{
                          startAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start">(knots)</InputAdornment>,
                      }}
                      onInput = {(e) =>{
                          e.target.value = Math.max(0, parseInt(e.target.value) ).toString().slice(0,12)
                      }}
                  />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={2}>
                  <TextField
                      required
                      id="standard-number"
                      label="Arrival delay"
                      onChange={(event) => this.props.handleChange("arrivalDelay", event)}
                      value={this.props.state.arrivalDelay}
                      type="number"
                      className={this.props.styles.textField}
                      margin="normal"
                      InputProps={{
                          startAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start">(minutes)</InputAdornment>,
                      }}
                      onInput = {(e) =>{
                          e.target.value = Math.max(0, parseInt(e.target.value) ).toString().slice(0,12)
                      }}
                  />
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={2}>
                  <TextField
                      required
                      id="standard-number"
                      label="Distance to target"
                      onChange={(event) => this.props.handleChange("distanceTarget", event)}
                      value={this.props.state.distanceTarget}
                      type="number"
                      className={this.props.styles.textField}
                      margin="normal"
                      InputProps={{
                          startAdornment: <InputAdornment position="start">(km)</InputAdornment>
                      }}
                      onInput = {(e) =>{
                          e.target.value = Math.max(0, parseInt(e.target.value) ).toString().slice(0,12)
                      }}
                  />
                </Grid>
              </Grid>
            </div>

        </Fragment>
      );
    }
}
```

Does somebody know where the problem is?

**UPDATE:**

I also tried this, but it gives me the same error:

```
const TopControls = () => (
  ...
);

export default TopControls;
```

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import SelectionPage from "../modes/SelectionPage";
import Main from "../modes/Main";
import Main2 from "../modes/Main2";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    renderView: 0
  };

  clickBtn = e => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
    this.setState({
      renderView: +e.target.parentNode.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    switch (this.state.renderView) {
      case 1:
        return <Main />;
      case 2:
        return <Main2 />;
      default:
        return <SelectionPage clickBtn={this.clickBtn} />;
    }
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you please share app.js file as error is in that file as per error message ?

Comment: @SahilArora: Done. Please check my update. "SelectionPage" has 2 buttons. If a user clicks button 1, then it's redirected to "Main". Otherwise, it's redirected to "Main2". I only have problems with "Main". The code of "Main2" works fine, but it does not contain children - everything is in a single component. Therefore I am simplifying everything now. I started from "Main". Once it works, I will do the same for "Main2".

Comment: Can you provide `Main.js` and `Main2.js`, please?

Comment: @JosuéCortina: The code of `Main.js` is the one at the beginning of a post. The code of `Main2.js` is irrelevant to this issue and also it's very-very long.

Comment: In main.js you do `return <Fragment> ... </Fragment>;`, can you try change that to `return (<Fragment> ... </Fragment>);`?

Comment: @nbokmans: I've just tried it. The same issue..

Comment: What happens if you just return `<div><Hello</div>` in `Main.render`?

Comment: @ScalaBoy It would be better if you create a fiddle or codesandbox that would reproduce your problem. That way it would be easier to debug and faster to resolve.

Comment: @JosuéCortina: In this case I see "Hello" on a screen.

Comment: So, the problem is on `Main.render`, try getting rid of `<Fragment>`, just return `<TopControls>`

Comment: @JosuéCortina: Ok, thanks. This seems to almost solve the problem. Now I get "TypeError: Cannot read property 'windIntensity' of null" for `value={this.state.windIntensity}`. It seems that `state` is not passed to `TopControls`.

Comment: @AnaLizaPandac: You are right. I am setting it up.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/jqvkqy29w

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can not pass the `state` directly to the child component. You have two main ways to resolve that issue.

## First option

You can to pass those values as `props`. Change `state={this.state}` by `...this.state` (*spread operator*):

#### Main.js

```
render() {
    return <Fragment>
        <TopControls handleChange={this.handleChange} styles={styles} ...this.state/>
    </Fragment>
}
```

and get those values directly from the `props` in `TopControls.js`:

#### TopControls.js

```
render() {
    ...
    value={this.props.holdingTime}
    ...
}
```

## Second option

Just use a different prop for passing the state:

#### Main.js

```
render() {
    return <Fragment>
        <TopControls myState={this.state} handleChange={this.handleChange} styles={styles} />
    </Fragment>
}
```

#### TopControls.js

```
render() {
    ...
    value={this.props.myState.holdingTime}
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I created a sandbox environment that reproduce my issue. Sorry for not doing it initially: https://codesandbox.io/s/jqvkqy29w

Comment: @ScalaBoy try my answer and let me know. If this dont work I will check your codesanbdbox

Comment: Now everything works in codesandbox. I just had `this.state.windIntensity` instead of `this.props.state.windIntensity`. So, it works with `state={this.state}`. But in my local setup I have a problem with `Fragment`. If I delete `Fragment`, everything works. Otherwise fails. In codesandbox the same code works well with `Fragment`. Do you know why it happens?

Comment: Well, I understood why it happens in my local setup. It's because I have more children components besides `TopControls`and these children components are empty so far.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `return` statement under the `render` function in your `app.js`.

```
renderComponent() {
  switch (this.state.renderView) {
    case 1:
      return <Main />;
    case 2:
      return <Main2 />;
    default:
      return <SelectionPage clickBtn={this.clickBtn} />;
  }
}

render() {
    return this.renderComponent();
}
```

I modified the code a bit but it's the same idea.

Comment: @JosuéCortina I encountered this problem before because of the missing `return` statement so this solution would be worth a try.

Comment: Thanks. I check it out, but received the same error.

Comment: @ScalaBoy It would be better if you create a fiddle or codesandbox that would reproduce your problem. That way it would be easier to debug and faster to resolve.